# Acumatica Account Details Not Matching Historical Inventory Valuation Report

Tags: acumatica

We are comparing these two reports as I mentioned and noticed that they do not match with the Inventory Account. Is it possible that they could be calculating a different way for each other? For example, you can say that it always seems that the Historical Inventory Balance is always about $120,000.00 less than the other. We have compared multiple reports multiple times and keep coming up with the same result. We have compared inventory items within the two reports and they seem to match, but something is still off. I have checked how the report is designed in the report designer and cannot come up with any solutions. Does anyone else seem to have this problem, idea, or are we completely missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it possible that they could be calculating a different way for each other?
```

You're not missing anything. Because the results are different it is logical to assume this is almost a fact.

The reports could be pulling data from the same source but applying different filtering. If that's the case, the fastest way to debug this issue is to dump and compare the SQL requests executed by the reports.

You can do so by opening the Trace window from the report page:
[image]

Then you launch the report and refresh the Trace window, the full SQL request will be available in the trace details. You can then execute it in Microsoft SQL Management Studio and compare the results. I suggest removing filters one by one until you find the ones which yields different results. You can also dump SQL requests of most Acumatica web page by using the Request Profiler screen (SM205070).[image]